# Prevent output interference in the background process

Tags: bash

i have spinner function

```
spinner(){
    while :;do for s in / - \\ \|;do printf "\r[$s] ${bold}$1$reset\r";sleep 0.2;done;done
}
```

and other 3 functions

```
func1(){

    echo "Start Function 1 "
    spinner "func1" & PID="$!"
    sleep 20   
    kill ${PID}
}

func2(){
    echo "Start Function 2 "
    spinner "func2" & PID="$!"
    sleep 30   
    kill ${PID}
}

func3(){
    echo "Start Function 3 "
    spinner "func3" & PID="$!"
    sleep 50   
    kill ${PID}
}

func1&
func2&
func3
```

the output will be

```
Start Function 1
Start Function 2
Start Function 3
# and here will be spinner function
```

When turned on, all the outputs of the spinner for each function are in the same line and replace the previous spinner output till the function end

I need each spinner to print in a different line from the other spinner so that there is no interference

i need output be like

```
Start Function 1
# spinner function for function 1
Start Function 2
# spinner function for function 1
Start Function 3
# spinner function for function 1
```

Comment: This question is really confused.  Do you want the spinners to run in parallel and then produce their output sequentially?  Or do you want them to run sequentially?

Comment: Or do you want them to run in parallel and produce output simultaneously ... but in without overwriting each other on the screen.  If >this< is what you need, you will most likely need to write a custom program.  (It strikes me as to difficult to do using a shell script.)

Comment: @Stephen C, if the flock output control is only for the actual output actions within each background process, they would connect and disconnect repeatedly for only their output steps, not the sleep times, so I believe it would achieve his objectives.

Comment: Well even that is hard.  The spinners need to use escape sequences to move the console cursor to the specific spinner's line on the screen.  This is the kind of thing that is simpler to do in C / C++ using a curses library or equivalent in your preferred HLL.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at using [flock](/questions/tagged/flock).

An example would be as follows:

```
flock -x ${LOCK_FILE} ${SCRIPT_or_COMMAND}
```

If ${LOCK_FILE} is busy/exists, other processes that want to access it will hold until it is available.

flock will remove/release the lock when the ${SCRIPT_or_COMMAND} process is completed.

I am *assuming* that flock manages a first-in/first-out access to a specified lock file to ensure integrity of sequencing.  Someone else would need to confirm that for you.

Comment: Using `flock` like this would cause the spinners to run sequentially.  If the OP wants that, the *simple* and *obvious* solution is to not put the first 2 spinners into the background!  So I would infer this is not what the OP wanted.